# Nginx forwarding to different app's different path using `#` symbol

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, path, location

Quick question. We have two apps. Ports `3001` and `3002`. Our domain is `www.domain.com`.
What we want to have it once person enters `www.domain.com/pathname` we want them to be redirected into another app's specific path.
How to do it?

We already came up to this in my nginx

```
location /pathname/ {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3002/;
    }
```

It nearly works. However, our app under `3002` works on path `/#/pathname`. 
We can access it by typing `www.domain.com/pathname/#/pathname`. We want to access same link by typing `www.domain.com/pathname`.

How to shorten it? What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

## (upd) Just redirect `/pathname` to `/pathname/#/pathname`

According to your comment, you want just redirect from `/pathname` to `/pathname/#/pathname`

Try these combined directives:

- `rewrite` to append `#` and `fragment identifier`
- and `proxy_pass` to reverse proxy to the app.

E.g.:

```
location /short_path_name/ {
  rewrite ^ /pathname/#/$uri permanent;
  break;        
}
location /pathname/ {
  proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3002/;
}
```

And use `www.domain.com/short_path_name/` link for your app.

## Unfortunately, nginx can't see the `fragment identifier`

Unfortunately, you can't. Because server never get the **[fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)** from browser.

> The fragment identifier functions differently to the rest of the URI: its processing is exclusively client-sided with no participation from the web server

Naming a bit amusing, but it has a long history. See [TBL (1997): Fragment Identifiers on URIs](https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html):

> The URI reference is a thing you build by taking a URI for an information object, adding a "#" sign and then a **Fragement identifier**. (The last term is historical, so try not to thinl of it necessarily identifying a fragment).

## Workarounds

There are workarounds, e.g. encode hashtag symbol into `%23` but I'm not sure is it your way.

## Handle request arguments with nginx

**Note**: rewriting url, nginx can preserve request arguments if you add `?` at the end of `rewrite` directive.

See [Nginx rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) manual:

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended, for example:
>
> ```
>    rewrite ^/users/(.*)$ /show?user=$1? last;
> ```

Comment: You mean nginx ignore everything that follows after ```#```? As in this case ```#/pathname```?

For us whatever works. Because currently URL is way too long

Comment: I mean that client (i.e. browser) doesn't send that remaining part of url to the web-server.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I don't need browser to send it. What I had in mind, if person types ```www.domain.com/pathname``` to the browser, nginx would see that the path is ```/pathname``` and automatically redirect user to ```www.domain.com/pathname/#/pathname``` behind the scenes. Sorry if it sounds confusing

Comment: Aha, thx! Have you tryied smth like this? `proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3002/#/pathname;`

Comment: @zeromaro just updated answer, try to use **two** directives.

Comment: Yes. It gives ```Bad Request```. Same ```Bad Request``` appears from ```proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002/#/pathname**/**;```

Comment: we managed to leave it as
```
location /pathname {
        rewrite /pathname/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3002/#/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }
```

We were not able to find a solution how to cut the corners on paths. So now people can reach out our different app via writing ```www.domain.com/pathname/#/pathname```. Thank you for trying to help!